# C# Turning an IEnumerable function that uses Dynamic linq into an IQueryable function

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic-linq

I've got this static function that returns the filtered list of items based on one or more filter items. It works but its set up to return an `IEnumerable`. The thing about this is that I still want to add to the expressionTree before compiling the set of expressions and executing it as a whole..

This is my current filter code modified from [Pashov](http://www.pashov.net/code/dynamic+filters).

```
namespace JobsLedger.API.ControllerServices.Shared.OrderAndFIlterHelpers {

    public class ExpressionFilter {
        public string PropertyName { get; set; }
        public object Value { get; set; }
        public Comparison Comparison { get; set; }
    }

    public enum Comparison {
        Equal,
        LessThan,
        LessThanOrEqual,
        GreaterThan,
        GreaterThanOrEqual,
        NotEqual,
        Contains, //for strings
        StartsWith, //for strings
        IndexOf, //for strings
        EndsWith, //for strings
        BoolTest, //for bools
    }
    public static class DynamicFilteringHelper {
        public static IEnumerable<T> ConstructAndExpressionTree<T>(IQueryable<T> source, List<ExpressionFilter> filters) {
            if (filters.Count == 0)
                return null;

            ParameterExpression param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "t");
            Expression exp = null;

            if (filters.Count == 1) {
                exp = ExpressionRetriever.GetExpression<T>(param, filters[0]);
            }
            else {
                exp = ExpressionRetriever.GetExpression<T>(param, filters[0]);
                for (int i = 1; i < filters.Count; i++) {
                    exp = Expression.And(exp, ExpressionRetriever.GetExpression<T>(param, filters[i]));
                }
            }

            var test = source.Where(Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(exp, param).Compile());
                return test;
            
        }




        public static class ExpressionRetriever {
            private static MethodInfo containsMethod = typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains", new Type[] { typeof(string), typeof(StringComparison) });
            private static MethodInfo startsWithMethod = typeof(string).GetMethod("StartsWith", new Type[] { typeof(string), typeof(StringComparison) });
            private static MethodInfo endsWithMethod = typeof(string).GetMethod("EndsWith", new Type[] { typeof(string), typeof(StringComparison) });

            private static MethodInfo booleanEqualMethod = typeof(bool).GetMethod("Equals", new Type[] { typeof(bool) });

            public static Expression GetExpression<T>(ParameterExpression param, ExpressionFilter filter) {
                MemberExpression member = Expression.Property(param, filter.PropertyName);
                ConstantExpression constant = Expression.Constant(filter.Value);
                ConstantExpression comparisonType = Expression.Constant(StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
                switch (filter.Comparison) {
                    case Comparison.Equal:
                        return Expression.Equal(member, constant);
                    case Comparison.GreaterThan:
                        return Expression.GreaterThan(member, constant);
                    case Comparison.GreaterThanOrEqual:
                        return Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(member, constant);
                    case Comparison.LessThan:
                        return Expression.LessThan(member, constant);
                    case Comparison.LessThanOrEqual:
                        return Expression.LessThanOrEqual(member, constant);
                    case Comparison.NotEqual:
                        return Expression.NotEqual(member, constant);
                    case Comparison.Contains:
                        return Expression.Call(member, containsMethod, constant, comparisonType);
                    case Comparison.StartsWith:
                        return Expression.Call(member, startsWithMethod, constant, comparisonType);
                    case Comparison.IndexOf:
                        return Expression.NotEqual(
                            Expression.Call(
                                member,
                                "IndexOf",
                                null,
                                Expression.Constant(filter.Value, typeof(string)),
                                Expression.Constant(StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase, typeof(StringComparison))
                            ),
                            Expression.Constant(-1, typeof(int))
                        );
                    case Comparison.EndsWith:
                        return Expression.Call(member, endsWithMethod, constant);
                    case Comparison.BoolTest:
                        return Expression.Call(member, booleanEqualMethod, constant);
                    default:
                        return null;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

At the end of the DynamicFilteringHelper method it has the expresson:

```
var test = source.Where(Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(exp, param).Compile());
```

This compiles the expressions and applies it to the source using a "where".

I wanted to instead produce an expressionTree that the sort function could add to before compiling.. In this, because its returning an `IEnumerable` it's been compiled and I would like to compile it after filtering and sorting first.

So I started to put together a Call that combined all the filtering expressions and applied it against the source using "where".

```
        var filteredExpressions = Expression.Lambda(exp, param);

        MethodCallExpression call = Expression.Call(
            typeof(Queryable),
            "where",
            new[] { typeof(T) },
            source.Expression,
            Expression.Quote(filteredExpressions)
            );
        return source.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(call);
```

This does not work and I get `"Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object."`

Is there a way to return the expressonTree so that it can be added onto before I compile and retrieve the results? Or am I OK to compile this and then use it for Sort function..

I get the impression its best to create the expression tree in its entirety before executing it so thats why I wanted to return an IQueryable rather than IEnumerable...

Extra info on the sort method..

Just for your information I next want to call this sort static sort function..

```
public static class DynamicOrderingHelper {
        public static IOrderedQueryable<T> OrderByAndThenBy<T>(IQueryable<T> source, List<KeyValuePair<string, SortDirection>> sortItems) {
            IOrderedQueryable<T> sortedSource = null;

            for (int i = 0; i < sortItems.Count; i++) {
                if (i == 0) {
                    sortedSource = sortItems[0].Value == SortDirection.asc ? OrderingHelper(source, sortItems[0].Key, false, false) : OrderingHelper(source, sortItems[0].Key, true, false);
                }
                else {
                    sortedSource = sortItems[i].Value == SortDirection.asc ? OrderingHelper(sortedSource, sortItems[i].Key, false, true) : OrderingHelper(sortedSource, sortItems[i].Key, true, true);
                }

            }
            return sortedSource;
        }

        private static IOrderedQueryable<T> OrderingHelper<T>(IQueryable<T> source, string propertyName, bool descending, bool anotherLevel) {
            ParameterExpression param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), string.Empty); // I don't care about some naming
            MemberExpression property = Expression.PropertyOrField(param, propertyName);
            LambdaExpression sort = Expression.Lambda(property, param);

            MethodCallExpression call = Expression.Call(
                         typeof(Queryable),
                         (!anotherLevel ? "OrderBy" : "ThenBy") + (descending ? "Descending" : string.Empty),
                         new[] { typeof(T), property.Type},
                         source.Expression,
                         Expression.Quote(sort));

            return (IOrderedQueryable<T>)source.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(call);
        }
```

**EDIT**

As Ivan suggested I did this and the return type has come back with "Operation invalid due to the current state of the object". I thought that this meant that it needed to be compiled but it wont accept that on IQueryable and .ToList() doesnt work either..

by the way this happens on the first of the two lines below.. source has 21 records but comes back with that error:

```
var test = source.Where(Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(exp, param));
            return test;
```

[image]

Comment: Change the return type to `IQueryable<T>` and remove `.Compile()` from `source.Where` call.

Comment: Regarding edit: Exception stack trace indicates that you are using a **preview (beta)** version of EF Core 3.0. Preview versions are unstable and many things doesn't work as expected. You could be hitting a bug/not implemented feature (they are in a process of rewriting the whole query processing pipeline). Try using the latest stable EF Core 2.x and wait for 3.0 release (or at least release candidate).

Comment: Im sorry but Id like to think that the developers over there might have this a little more polished than that.. We are on preview 3 now.. I also note that the sort function works returning a IOrderedQueryable so why shouldnt the filter method be able to do the same...

Comment: You could also just use https://github.com/StefH/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core to apply dynamic linq on your database.